# Insert image in excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

In my Office 2010 xlsm sheet I have created a fixed size Image ActiveX control called `Image1`. The following macros should in my opinion set the image path to the one which specified in cell `B3`, but it fails with "Run-time error '424': Object required" error message at the line Image1.Picture. I checked that `imPath` is equal to `"C:\some\valid\image\path.jpg"`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        imPath = Range("B3")
        Image1.Visible = True         
        Image1.Picture = imPath
        Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom   
        Image1.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone    
        Image1.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
    End If
End Sub
```

What is wrong here? BTW, is there any way to check if the specified file actually exists?

Comment: Here are some references related to the answer provided to help answer the What is Wrong here question: [Using the Image Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242027(v=VS.60).aspx) [LoadPicture Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264946(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I was searching in the wrong place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look into excel-help, searching for picture, suggests that you use this line:

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(imPath)
```

To check if the file exists, use a FileSystemObject

```
Dim fs as variant
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.FileExists(imPath)
```

*edit*

by the way you can use

```
imPath = Target.value
```

to set imPath (not tested, but quite sure of this)

Comment: +1 for beating me to it. If you want to avoid using the FileSystem Object, youc an also do this: `If Dir(imPath) <> "" then` if Dir returns an empty string then the path is not valid.

Comment: thanks, I love having different approaches in one place! Find this solution with `Dir` in this case even better, because there is no need for a FSO, if there will be only one quick existance check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would say, the correct would be `Dir$(imPath)`